# Spring @RequestBody does not look up object

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm writing a REST service using Spring-MVC/Hibernate and it seems @RequestBody is the recommended way to accept a bunch of parameters and map it into a POJO. However, it seems that the ID sent via POST gets translated into null instead of the actual object. Some sample code will explain better.

The service is straightforward:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ServiceResponse addTx(@RequestBody Transaction tx) {
    ...
    return ServiceResponse;
}
```

The Transaction entity has an Account entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Transaction")
public class Transaction {
    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="accountId")
    private Account account;
    @Column(name="amount")
    private int amount;
    ...
}
```

The POST request payload from my browser reads:

```
{code: "ascasc", amount: 23, accountId: 1, ... }
```

But at the server-side, the constructed Transaction object has an Account value of null. i.e. that accountId of 1 does not get translated into the Account object. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's disappointing this is not as straightforward as I imagined. I've gone back to using [@RequestBody String] and parsing the JSON to manually build the Transaction object, which sort-of defeats the purpose of these end-to-end mapping ideals.

Comment: This behavior is correct, `@RequestBody` knows nothing about your persistence layer, it just maps the request body to a specified object. And when you post accountId, it doesn't find it as the property of target object (there is only account), so it skips it. Maybe you could post `{..., account: {id: 1}, ...}` in which case it should be mapped to an empty account object with ID filled out. Then Hibernate would actually lookup the real account based on that during merge for example. I haven't tested it but feel free to give it a try

Comment: This solved my problem, though Hibernate did not actually look up the Account object. It simply created an empty Account object with the supplied id that was sufficient to generate the correct insert query. Can you repost this as an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you describe is correct. When you use `@RequestBody`, it knows nothing about your persistence layer, it just maps the body of the request to the target object.

So when you post JSON containing `accountId`, Spring will try to find `accountId` property of the target object, but it doesn't exist (target object has only `account` property), so `accountId` will not be mapped. If you want the `accountId` to be correctly mapped, you must POST JSON like `{..., account: { id: 1 }, ...}`.

---

On a side note, it is a fairly common pattern to use transport objects for request/response object of web services and then map those to entity objects. You could then have `accountId` property in your transport object and then use that value when assembling the entity. One reason for this might be for example that you don't want to return certain model attributes from your webservices and you don't want to pollute your model layer with `@JsonIgnore` annotations for instance. This approach would also let you change your entity classes (e.g. rename some properties) without necessarily breaking your API. However this will add an extra layer of complexity, so you must decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: I'm a bit apprehensive about having 2 class definitions per entity that I have to keep in sync. My architecture isn't that complex for now, so the account: { id: 1 } suggestion will suffice. Thanks!

Comment: @tys I can understand that. I was once working on a project with two such layers (one transfer object for Spring MVC forms, one for transfering data between controllers and service based on which entities were assembled on service layers). When you wanted to change one model field you had to change entity, two transport objects, and three mapper methods (entity -> form, form -> service transport object, service transport object -> entity). Suffice it to say that changing something in the model was pretty lengthy process :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the annotation @JsonProperty - if you are using jackson

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="accountId")
@JsonProperty("account")
private Account account;
```

This will map the json property account to your account variable

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you were to POST `{..., account: {id: 1}, ...}` as I suggested then it would be mapped anyway, since the property is named the same (`account`), so in this case the `@JsonProperty` annotation would be not necessary. And if you POST `{..., accountId: 1, ...}` then the `@JsonProperty` annotation still wouldn't ensure that accountId will be mapped to id field in Account class, right?

Comment: Thats correct Bohuslav - the join column is needed for the db and the @JsonProperty needed if you want to accept a different name than account from your json. Alof of the times, the db field name, class field name and json value are all the same. But i am just throwing this suggestion out there in the event the user wants to use a different value from their Json. Like all things in Java - there are about 10 things to do everything and your answer is perfectly correct